# How to override the CSS default properties of Material UI on React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, vite, swc

I have some React project and I'm using the 'Table' component from Maerial UI.
That table with her components (TableHead, TableCell, TableRow etc.) have thier default CSS properties.
But when I'm trying to override that **in a suitable and right way for developing** I cannot change those properties somehow

I'm looking for a way to do that without TypeScript code, but only in the seperate CSS file
Someone have an advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to override the default CSS properties of the Material UI Table component in a separate CSS file without using TypeScript, you can use the global CSS overrides and default props in the Material UI theme. Here are the steps:
Create a new CSS file and import it into your React application using the "import" statement.
Define the global CSS overrides for the Table component in the CSS file. For example, you can use the following CSS code to change the background color of the TableHead component:
CSS

```
.MuiTableHead-root {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Create a new Material UI theme in your React application and set the global CSS overrides and default props for the Table component. For example, you can use the following code to create a new theme and set the global CSS overrides and default props:
JavaScript

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTableHead: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
      },
    },
  },
  props: {
    MuiTable: {
      size: 'small',
    },
    MuiTableCell: {
      size: 'small',
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

Apply the new theme to your React application using the "ThemeProvider" component. For example, you can use the following code to apply the new theme to your application:
JavaScript

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import theme from './theme';

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {/* Your application code */}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Remember to use reputable sources and follow best practices when creating and applying global CSS overrides and default props in Material UI. Additionally, you can refer to the official documentation and online resources for more information on using global CSS overrides and default props in Material UI.

Comment: Thanks for answering :-) The first way, of a separate CSS file is not working on MUI components - only on normal HTML, this is the first way I have tried. Regarding the second way, I have tried to avoid those ways (I wanted a pure CSS, but after searching I'm not sure this is exist), but it works and good enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% sure for this, but adding `!important` for class tags usually overrides css from non-class css modules.

i.e. `.className{ width:'100px'!important; }`

Comment: Thanks for answering :-) But, are you sure is that a recommended way? according to what I learned before, the '!important' isn't recommended for developers and it's for "emergency situations"

Comment: Check out this page https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/ . The docs has some info on how to do this. But it looks like someone answered the question better than I could have. Have a good day :)